# How to build a function that extracts information from a set of polygons at multiple points in R

Tags: r

I am new to R, and trying to build a simple function that calculates an average (mean) of Sum_MVKT extracted from a set of predefined point locations.

For this, I have two shapefiles named Traffic_Val (polygon), and StnLocations (points).

"Traffic_Val" contains a large number of polygons and each polygon has an unique value (Sum_MVKT).

"StnLocations" consists of multiple points that lie on top of polygons in "Traffic_Val".

Provided the predefined StnLocations, I'd like to extract the value from Traffic_Val at each station location and calculate the average.

Here is the R script that I have written so far..

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)

setwd("C:/Users/calculateTraffic") 

# load data:
SA <- readShapePoly('Traffic_Val.shp') # This file contains a list of traffic values named as "Sum_MVKT"
proj4string(SA) <- CRS("+init=epsg:26915") 


### Existing Station Locations ###
PtsLocation <- readShapePoints('stnLocations.shp')
names(PtsLocation@data)
names(PtsLocation@data)<-c("ID", "x", "y", "Site_desc")

plot(SA)
points(PtsLocation, pch = 1, col = 3)

###########################
#### calculateTraffic ##### 
###########################

calculateTraffic = function (PtsLocation)
{
  obs = PtsLocation
  if (missing(formulaString) || is.null(formulaString)) {
    eq = dum ~ 1
  } else eq = formulaString
  ############ changed following 'if statement' 
  if (!"data.frame" %in% getSlots(class(obs)) & (terms(eq)[[3]] ==  
                                               1 || all(all.vars(eq)[-1] %in% dimnames(coordinates(obs))[[2]]))) {
    obs = SpatialPointsDataFrame(obs, data = data.frame(dum = rep(1,
                                                              dim(coordinates(obs))[1])))
    names(obs) = as.character(eq[[2]])
  }

  meanTraffic <<- mean( )

  return(meanTraffic)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is a bit confusing. It sounds like you would like to aggregate the mean of values, located at points, based on the intersection with a polygon object.

Even if this is not exactly the case, this code should at least point you in the right direction.

```
require(sp)

# Create example data
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
sr <- list(sr1=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180114, 180553, 181127, 181477, 181294, 181007, 180409, 
  180162, 180114), c(332349, 332057, 332342, 333250, 333558, 333676, 
  332618, 332413, 332349)))),"1"),
sr2=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180042, 180545, 180553, 180314, 179955, 179142, 179437, 
  179524, 179979, 180042), c(332373, 332026, 331426, 330889, 330683, 
  331133, 331623, 332152, 332357, 332373)))),"2"),
sr3=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(179110, 179907, 180433, 180712, 180752, 180329, 179875, 
  179668, 179572, 179269, 178879, 178600, 178544, 179046, 179110),
  c(331086, 330620, 330494, 330265, 330075, 330233, 330336, 330004, 
  329783, 329665, 329720, 329933, 330478, 331062, 331086)))),"3"),
sr4=Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(180304, 180403,179632,179420,180304),
  c(332791, 333204, 333635, 333058, 332791)))),"4"))
srdf=SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(sr), data.frame(row.names=c("1","2","3","4"), PIDS=1:4))

plot(srdf)
  plot(meuse, pch=20, add=TRUE)

# Use over to add polygon ID's to meuse points
meuse@data <- data.frame(meuse@data, PID=(meuse %over% srdf))

# Use tapply to calculate mean for each polygon
tapply(meuse@data$copper, meuse@data$PID, FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I was able to figure it out from your example!